# Using Java beans as Grails domain classes

Tags: java, grails

There are many similar questions, but I couldn't find exactly how to use a POJO model in a grails application. Consider the following Java Bean:

```
package com.example.java;

public class UserBean {

    String name;
    String surname;
    Integer age;

    //--- assume setters and getters here
}
```

and a grails domain class:

```
package com.example.grails

class User extends com.example.java.UserBean {

    static constraints = {
        name(blank:false)
        surname()
        age()
    }
}
```

and a companion controller with scaffold=true. I am not sure whether this supposed to work but I didn't see anything suggesting otherwise. This compiles and runs fine, until I try to add a new user from the generated view. Then I get

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.example.grails.User
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why would you extend a POJO anyway? Groovy automatically generates getters and setters for you... just copy/paste the member variables into the domain class and call it good.

Comment: If you already have your domain model written in Java, how else would you write a grails application?

Comment: If your domain model is written in java using hibernate, you can use your hibernate mappings in grails to enable you to use your POJOs. I'm not familiar with how to do that though. Check out the "Grails and Hibernate" section of the user guide for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem on: [this spring.io blog post](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/26/reuse-your-hibernate-jpa-domain-model-with-grails/)

If your Java domain classes are hibernate mapped, you don't extend them in grails. All you have to do is to define the constraints in a separate file named UserBeanConstraints.groovy:

```
constraints = {
    name(blank:false)
    surname()
    age()
}
```

Comment: I don't know the tradition here for accepting one's own questions. I guess I'll accept this if it gets up votes.

Comment: i think you wanted the constraints the whole time instead of subclassing; I'd just clarify your answer and what you were trying to accomplish and then accept it.

Answer (score 3):

What does your `hibernate.cfg.xml` look like?

Make sure that your com.example.grails.User class is mapped:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
   <mapping package="com.example.grails" />
   <mapping class="com.example.grails.User" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configurations>
```

More details can be found: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html